# createBlobFromLocalFile should be a non-empty string - azure blob storage

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload a file to azure blob storage. I'm receiving it on the backend, but I keep getting the error `createBlobFromLocalFile should be a non-empty string` I"m receiving the file as you can see in console output, but I don't understand why I can't send it to blob storage. I've tried replacing the second parameter called `blob string` with `req.file, req,file.path, req.file.destination + filename`, but haven't been able to get it to store the file in blob. I appreciate any help!

app.js

```
app.post("/api/fileupload", checkAuth, upload, (req, res, next) => {

  console.log("req.file below");
  console.log(req.file);

  blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('testcontainer', req.file, "image.png", function (error, result, response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (!error) {
      // file uploaded
    }
  });

});
```

Console Output

```
req.file below
{ fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'blob',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: 'public/uploads/',
  filename: '18af517e9a94b2bdab02c7169b8b88a7',
  path: 'public\\uploads\\18af517e9a94b2bdab02c7169b8b88a7',
  size: 39367 }
TypeError: Parameter blob for function _createBlobFromLocalFile should be a non-empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [`documentation`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.node.js#L145), this should be the **path** of the local file (a string value) whereas you're passing an object as value of this parameter.

However, if you use `file.path` variable, it would still not work as it tells you the path of the file on the local computer and not the server on which your Node.js code is running. You will need to specify the path of the file on the server.

I answered a question just a few days ago where `formidable` package was used to parse the request to extract the file content. Though the answer is for the newer version of the SDK but you can use that to see how local file path on the server was identified. You may find it useful: [How to upload images and files to Azure Blob Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60458504/how-to-upload-images-and-files-to-azure-blob-node-js/60472547#60472547).

Comment: I've updated my code to reflect your answer from the other post. It doesn't seem to go inside the the form though. I'm not sure how to combine the code with my incoming file. It doesn't seem to go inside  ```form.parse``` from the looks of the console output. I appreciate your help!   updated code and console output: https://pastebin.com/y90xy66A

Comment: Can you try to output the “form” variable? Just wondering if you’ve installed and referenced right npm packages. Ideally, please edit your question and include updated code towards the bottom of your post.

Comment: Here's console.log(form) after it's defined. https://pastebin.com/846632cz