# Cannot upload file to Azure Blob Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure

Trying to upload a file to azure blob storage using @azure/storage-blob sdk in nodejs:

```
module.exports.createBlob = (blobName, containerName, blobContent) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const sharedKeyCredential = await this.createSharedAccessToken(blobName, 'c')
      const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
    `https://${process.env.AZURE_BLOB_ACCOUNT}.blob.core.windows.net`,
    sharedKeyCredential
      )
      const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)
      const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName)
      const blob = await blockBlobClient.upload(blobContent, blobContent.length) // implement later
      resolve(blob)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      reject(err)
    }
  })
}

module.exports.createSharedAccessToken = (blobName, permission) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(process.env.AZURE_BLOB_ACCOUNT, process.env.AZURE_BLOB_KEY)
    const containerName = process.env.AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME
    const startsOn = new Date()
    expiresOn.setMinutes(expiresOn.getMinutes() + parseInt(autoLogoutDuration.KeyValue))
    const blobSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
      containerName, // Required
      blobName, // Required
      permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse(permission), // Required
      startsOn: startsOn, // Required
    },
    sharedKeyCredential // StorageSharedKeyCredential - `new StorageSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey)`
    ).toString()
    resolve(decodeURI(blobSAS))
})
}
```

It keeps throwing a "NoAuthenticationInformation" error. The same creds work for downloading an existing blob but uploading is not working no matter what I try. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can refer to [Avoiding “AuthorizationFailed” error when hand-crafting Shared Access Signature for Azure Storage](https://gauravmantri.com/2020/02/21/avoiding-authorizationfailed-error-when-hand-crafting-shared-access-signature-for-azure-storage/), [How to upload images and files to Azure Blob Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60458504/how-to-upload-images-and-files-to-azure-blob-node-js) and [Stream uploaded file to Azure blob storage with Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317904/stream-uploaded-file-to-azure-blob-storage-with-node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed by this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs) , I tried to reproduce your issue ,but able to upload files into my azure blob container using **Node.js** without any authentication error.

As you are using shared key credential we need to have all those **permissions** in our portal as shown below:

[image]

Also i am using `@azure/storage-blob` sdk in `nodejs`  in my `package.json`  .

[image]

Also added `@azure/storage-blob` sdk in my `testupload.js` file

[image]

And added the below code into my `testupload.js` file as i have already created container i just commented the above screenshot code .

```js
const  account="testa";

const  sharedKeyCredential = new  StorageSharedKeyCredential("yourstorageaccountname", "your storage key connection string");

const  blobServiceClient1 = new  BlobServiceClient(

// When using AnonymousCredential, following url should include a valid SAS or support public access

`https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,

sharedKeyCredential

);

  

const  blobnewname="example2.txt"

blobContent="hi hello";

const  containerClient1 = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("test")

const  blockBlobClient1= containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobnewname)

const  blob = blockBlobClient1.upload(blobContent, blobContent.length)
```

Then i can able to test and upload my files to Azure blob container
Here are screenshot for reference:

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer this MS DOC :  [Azure Storage samples using v12 JavaScript client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-javascript?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#blob-samples)

**UPDATE:-**
As suggested by @Setanjan Roy

Alternate way:-
To get rid of this we can use  new BlobServiceClient( `https://${process.env.AZURE_BLOB_ACCOUNT}.blob.core.windows.net${sharedKeyCredential}` )

Comment: I am pretty sure the creds I am using has necessary permissions as the frontend team using Angular is able to upload a file easily. I actually was able to solve the issue by looking at their code. The issue was how the sas was being passed to the blob service client constructor. Here is how I did it :   new BlobServiceClient( `https://${process.env.AZURE_BLOB_ACCOUNT}.blob.core.windows.net${sharedKeyCredential}`
 )  Somehow it worked.